# Is this asymmetrically frozen ice cream an example of symmetry breaking?

Tags: thermodynamics, symmetry, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

Today I noticed my ice cream had frozen in an asymmetric pattern because I left it resting at an angle on the fridge. I'm wondering if  this is analogous to the concept of symmetry breaking as used in particle physics.

[image: Ice cream]

Comment: It is meant in context of asymmetry or rules, not asymmetry of reality. Similarly if I win a lottery today, but not tomorrow, it is not evidence of breaking of time translation symmetry.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Off-topic: Please don't let your ice cream melt and refreeze it https://www.thekitchn.com/3-reasons-why-you-probably-shouldnt-refreeze-melted-ice-cream-231988